# Uninitialized constexpr allowed with gcc

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Given the code

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int n;
    return 0;
}
```

, g++, with `-fpermissive`, emits only a warning, while clang++, also with `-fpermissive`, errors out, complaining about default initialization of an object of const type 'const int'. Now, I believe clang++'s behavior is the correct one. The question is if I'm missing something or not and maybe g++ not emitting an error is acceptable. Versions : clang++ 7.0.1, g++ 8.3.1, Fedora 29, amd64.

Comment: A warning is a diagnostic (all that is required by the standard).  Therefore both compilers are correct.

Comment: `-fpermissive` generally turns errors into warnings. It seems counterproductive to the question.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but since `clang++` emits an error, even with `-fpermissive`, I'm thinking that one compiler is more lax than the other regarding this. And if I'm reading the standard correctly, it should be an error.

Comment: With `-fpermissive` you're explicitly telling the compiler you want to play fast and loose with the rules of the standard. You can't expect the compiler to follow the rules when you explicitly tell it "Hey just trust me; don't follow the rules"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard primarily deals with diagnostics and not with errors or warnings. So all that a conforming compiler is required to emit is a diagnostic which both of these compilers do.

As to why `-fpermissive` produces only a warning in GCC in this case but an error in Clang depends on the approach that these compilers have taken with respect to the `-fpermissive` option.

As per [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options):

> `-fpermissive`
>
> Downgrade some diagnostics about nonconformant code from errors to warnings. Thus, using `-fpermissive` allows some nonconforming code to compile.

Clang did not have the `-fpermissive` option at first. It was added later. From the information we have online, [Clang's approach](https://reviews.llvm.org/D58154) to this option is:

> `-fpermissive`
>
> Do not error on language extensions. Diagnostics for invalid code using known
>     language extensions in the current language mode are downgraded to at most a
>     warning.

So in Clang only language extensions are downgraded to warning status. If it is not a language extension (as in the given example), it will not be downgraded to warning and will be diagnosed as an error.